# Can you get dogs or cats without the Pets expansion?

Tags: the-sims-4

Can you get dogs and cats without the Sims 4 Pets installed?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. Just a speculation though, I don't have the game or know much about it.

Comment: What do you meanby "get dogs and cats"? Pets? Wild animals?

Comment: BTW I mean pets like dogs and cats and other animals you can get in the expansion packs on the sims 3 not wild animals

Answer (score 4):

No, having pets (aside from fish in bowls) requires the *Cats & Dogs* expansion pack.